# Access SVG element attribute with jquery's 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, this

I'm trying to access an SVG element's attribute via a jQuery function. I can access each element by ID just fine, but what I really want is to access the element via 'this'.

```
function drawPPF(){
    if (!$("#spreadFormPPF1").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).attr('y', 5);
    $("#spreadFormPPF1").fadeIn("slow");
    } else if ($("#spreadFormPPF1").is(":visible") && !$("#spreadFormPPF2").is(":visible") ) {
        $(this).attr('y', 5);
        $("#spreadFormPPF2").fadeIn("slow");
    } else if ($("#spreadFormPPF2").is(":visible")) 
    {
    $(this).attr('y', 5);
    $("#spreadFormPPF3").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#spreadFormPPFInstruct").fadeIn("slow");  
    }   
};
```

and the html is

```
 <svg id="spreadOutSVG1" width="600px" height="200px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <image x="50" y="10" width="300" height="200" xlink:href="images/flipcard.jpg" id="card1"onclick="drawPPF();" /> 
 <image x="60" y="10" width="300" height="200" xlink:href="images/flipcard.jpg" id="card2" onclick="drawPPF();" />
 ... 
</svg>
```

When I have "this" replaced with #card1 or #card2, it does what I want it to (i.e. move the image to y=5 from y=10). But what I really want to happen is for whatever SVG element is selected - you know, THIS - to have its attribute changed, not a specific id. What am I doing wrong? Thanks - I'm super new at all this and appreciate your help!

Comment: Try `onclick="drawPPF.call(this);"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Function.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass a custom context to a function execution

```
<svg id="spreadOutSVG1" width="600px" height="200px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image x="50" y="10" width="300" height="200" xlink:href="images/flipcard.jpg" id="card1" onclick="drawPPF.call(this);" />
    <image x="60" y="10" width="300" height="200" xlink:href="images/flipcard.jpg" id="card2" onclick="drawPPF.call(this);" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did work, but unfortunately if the images are closely overlapping, it only affects the "top" image. ???

Answer (score 0):

A good way to find out what `$(this)` actually is is to print it out to the console whenever you click on any of the cards.

```
function drawPPF(){
    $this = $(this);
    console.log($this);
    ....
}
```

Then by opening the Developer Tools on Chrome (Command + Option + i) or Firebug on Firefox (Command + Option + i), you can see what $(this) is by looking at the console.

There you would find that $(this) is undefined, reason being you are triggering the function inline. One solution for this is to add a click event to the cards through jQuery

```
$('#card1').on('click', function(){
   $this = $(this);
   console.log($this);
   ... //Rest of function, which would be same as top
});
```

Here you will see that every time you click on a card, it will show which one in the console.

Even with the way you have the above function defined, all you would need to do is

```
$('#card1, #card2').on('click', drawPPF);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't figure out where your lines of code should have gone. I couldn't make this work for me.